# How to create a constraint for unique (not including order) JSONB column in postgresql

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I am looking for a way to create a constraint that will verify the values in a JSONB column are unique, however i need them to also be unique when compared without taking order into account, so JSONB comparison / hashing is not valid for this case.

In order to check if 2 JSONB objects are equal, i check if they contain each other

```sql
select t.a @> t.b and  t.a <@ t.b
from (
SELECT
    '{"foo": 42, "bar": ["value", 5]}'::jsonb as a,
    '{"bar": [5, "value"], "foo": 42}'::jsonb as b
) as t
```

Specifically i am looking for an SQLAlchemy solution, but a raw postgresql solution will probably help a lot.

Comment: Is the JSON always an array of strings?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe No - fixed example

Comment: `foo` and `bar` will be reordered automatically, but I doubt that there is a good solution.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe keys are reordered automatically however lists are not?
is there a way to reorder the lists automatically on insert?
I don't need to maintain original ordering, but i also don't want to order it in application code

Comment: Yes, the order of arrays is preserved. You could write a complicated function that pre-processes JSON values that way. I told you that there is probably no easy solution for this.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - i think i found a pretty straightforward implementation which i posted as an answer - is there any caveat for that method?

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to add a trigger that calls a function that checks if there is already a jsonb which contains and is contained by the one that is being inserted

trigger:

```sql
create trigger trigger1
before insert
on json_table
for each row
execute procedure func;
```

function:

```sql
create function func returns trigger
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
same_json json_table%rowtype;
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE')  THEN
        select * from json_table
        into same_json
        where NEW.json @> json_table.json and NEW.json <@ json_table.json;

        IF FOUND then
            RAISE NOTICE 'Not inserting json, an equal json is already in the table: id=%', same_json.id;
            return NULL;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

I then created a manual alembic migration which added the trigger and function - see https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/issues/504#issuecomment-441887901